# tensorflow training from tf.data.dataset from tfrecords outputs ValueError: Missing data for input "input_2". You passed a data dictionary with keys

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.data.dataset

python version 3.7.11, tensorflow version 2.7.0

I've created tfrecords from pandas dataframe and trying to load into tf.data.dataset then train it using tensorflow.

Reading and parsing tfrecords as follows:

```
feature_desc = {
    "year": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'prev_year_spend': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'prev_year_n_buy': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'age': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'price': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)}

serialized_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('filename_0.tfrecord')
```

then from various examples they seem to split features and label into tuple so I've parsed it:

```
def parse(serialized_example):
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_desc)
    y = example.pop('price')
    return example, y
    
dataset = serialized_dataset.map(parse)
```

When I print one record I get:

```
for e in dataset.take(1):
    print(e)
>>> ({'age': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.53333336>, 
'prev_year_n_buy': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, 
'prev_year_spend': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, 'year': 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>}, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), 
dtype=float32, numpy=0.4220339>)
```

tuple of dictionary and tensor.

Training it on simple linear regression:
"""
tensorflow Linear Regression

Does really bad on test set, values are way off compared to sklearn...
"""

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
    optimizer = 'sgd',
    metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
history = model.fit(dataset)
```

I get following error `ValueError: Missing data for input "input_2". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['age', 'prev_year_n_buy', 'prev_year_spend', 'year']. Expected the following keys: ['input_2']`.

For tabular datasets what is the best way to split features and label within tf.data.dataset so it could be trained on tf models?